# Esp-now reacting like bloating in Many-to-one setup

Tags: esp8266, esp

I have project which 3 esp01 controller and 1 nodemcu 12-E receiver which gives scores.
Trying to read all input freely from controllers but when i use 3 at same time or pressing button too quickly nodemcu seems to halts and doesn't react or get messages.

Is my simple if algorithm is flawed or did i hit a hardware barrier.
I used working button library for single click event in ESP-01

For fundamental setup i used tutorial.
Esp01 Sender

```
#include <Button2.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <espnow.h>
#define RED 2
#define BLUE 0

// REPLACE WITH RECEIVER MAC Address
//Esp8266 80:7D:3A:37:C5:66
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x80, 0x7D, 0x3A, 0x37, 0xC5, 0x66};

// Set your Board ID (ESP32 Sender #1 = BOARD_ID 1, ESP32 Sender #2 = BOARD_ID 2, etc)
#define BOARD_ID  1

// Structure example to send data
// Must match the receiver structure
typedef struct struct_message {
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called test to store variables to be sent
struct_message myData;

  // Init ESP-NOW
Button2 buttonA, buttonB;

unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

// Callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(uint8_t *mac_addr, uint8_t sendStatus) {
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status: ");
  if (sendStatus == 0){
    Serial.println("Delivery success");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Delivery fail");
  }
}

//void begin(byte attachTo, byte buttonMode = INPUT_PULLUP, boolean activeLow  = true);
 
void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(0,INPUT_PULLUP);
  
  buttonA.begin(RED);
  buttonA.setClickHandler(click);

  buttonB.begin(BLUE);
  buttonB.setClickHandler(click);
  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  } 
  // Set ESP-NOW role
  esp_now_set_self_role(ESP_NOW_ROLE_CONTROLLER);

  // Once ESPNow is successfully init, we will register for Send CB to
  // get the status of Trasnmitted packet
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
  
  // Register peer
  esp_now_add_peer(broadcastAddress, ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE, 1, NULL, 0);

}
 
void loop() {
  buttonA.loop();
  buttonB.loop();
}
void click(Button2& btn) {
    if (btn == buttonA) {
      myData.id = BOARD_ID;
      myData.x = 1;
      myData.y = 0;
      esp_now_send(0, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));
      Serial.println("A clicked");
    } else if (btn == buttonB) {
      myData.id = BOARD_ID;
      myData.x = 0;
      myData.y = 1;
      esp_now_send(0, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));
      Serial.println("B clicked");
    }
}
```

NodeMCU 12-E Receiver

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <espnow.h>
#include <Arduino.h>


#define  LED0 D0
#define  LED1 D1
#define  LED2 D2
#define  LED3 D3
#define  LED4 D4
#define  LED5 D5
#define  LED6 D6
#define  LED8 D8
#define  LED7 D7



// Structure example to receive data
// Must match the sender structure
typedef struct struct_message {
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

// Create a structure to hold the readings from each board
struct_message board1;
struct_message board2;
struct_message board3;

// Create an array with all the structures
struct_message boardsStruct[3] = {board1, board2, board3};

// refree
/*
void ref1(int x, int y){

  if (x == 1 ){
      digitalWrite(LED7, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED7, LOW);
    }
  else  if (y == 1 ){
      
      digitalWrite(LED8, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED8, LOW);
    }


}

void ref2(int x, int y){

  if (x == 1 ){
      digitalWrite(LED6, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED6, LOW);
    }

  else if (y == 1 ){
      
      digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    }


}

void ref3(int x, int y){

  if (x == 1){
      digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
    }

  else if (y == 1){
      
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
      delay(5);
      digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
    }


}
  */



// Callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(uint8_t * mac_addr, uint8_t *incomingData, uint8_t len) {
  char macStr[18];
  Serial.print("Packet received from: ");
  snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
           mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
  Serial.println(macStr);
  memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
  Serial.printf("Board ID %u: %u bytes\n", myData.id, len);
  Serial.println(myData.id);

  
  if (myData.id==1 ){
    ref1(myData.x, myData.y);
  }
  if (myData.id==2 ){
    ref2(myData.x, myData.y);
  }
  if (myData.id==3 ){
    ref3(myData.x, myData.y);
  }
  

  // Update the structures with the new incoming data
  boardsStruct[myData.id-1].x = myData.x;
  boardsStruct[myData.id-1].y = myData.y;
  boardsStruct[myData.id-1].id = myData.id;
  Serial.printf("x value: %d \n", boardsStruct[myData.id-1].x);
  Serial.printf("y value: %d \n", boardsStruct[myData.id-1].y);
  Serial.printf("id value: %d \n", boardsStruct[myData.id-1].id);
  Serial.println();
  
  
  
  
}



void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED6, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED7, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED8, OUTPUT);
  
  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  
  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info
  esp_now_set_self_role(ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE);
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
  
}

void loop(){

   
}
```

Comment: don't print inside ISRs ... set a flag instead ... move message printing to inside `loop()` ...print a message if flag is set

Comment: what it the meaning of ISR ? and can you give and example snip of pseudocode.

Comment: I set it up with flags but no hope. Still stuck now trying to RingBuffer.

Comment: ISR - interrupt service routine ... it is the callback function

Comment: take out the delay() and print() lines, and see if it works then.